# Searching Array in .txt File VB.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm doing a school project for vb and have been asked to write a program that creates a single dimension string array consisting of the names of the last 6 people to win a golf tournament. The user has to enter a name in a text box to search an array. If the name does appear, a message box should display the players name and winning year
If it doesn't appear a message should appear explaining this also.

I've written out the code but have come across an error {'i' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to it's protection level}

I have researched this error and have tried multiple things but the code still wont work. I woul appreciate any help thank you

```
       Imports System.IO
         Public Class Form1
              Dim Player() As String = {"Tim Wood", "Vince Singer","Donal Clark", "Patrick Hartnett", "Peter Nicholson", "Chris Montgomery"}

              Dim WinningYear() As Integer = {2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007}



Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'Searches array for player
    Dim strPlayer As String = txtPlayer.Text
    Dim intYearWon As Integer

    For i As Integer = 0 To 6

        If i = 6 Then

            MessageBox.Show(strPlayer & " has not won the tournament in the last 6 years")
    End If
    Next

    intYearWon = WinningYear(i)
    If strPlayer = Player(i) Then
        MessageBox.Show(strPlayer & " won in " & intYearWon)

    End If

End Sub


   End Class
```

Comment: your i var is declared as the loop indexer so it only exists in the loop code, not afterwards.  It also isnt actually searching the array you need to compare `strPlayer` to each array element (`Player(i)) and then you need a var to save the index of any match found

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well Here's how you'd fix your current `btnSearch_Click()` method:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'Searches array for player
    Dim strPlayer As String = txtPlayer.Text
    Dim intYearWon As Integer
    Dim success as boolean = False
    For i As Integer = 0 To Players.count - 1

        If strPlayer.equals(Player(i)) Then
            intYearWon = WinningYear(i)
            success = True
            MessageBox.Show(strPlayer & " won in " & intYearWon)  
        End If

    Next

    If Not success Then MessageBox.Show(strPlayer & " has not won the tournament in the last 6 years")

End Sub
```

However, I would look into using a `Dictionary(Of Int32, String)` for the years and names. Notice that I choose the year to be the key and the name to be the value. That's because only one person can win each year, but each person can win multiple years. Here's how you would use a `Dictionary(Of Int32, String)` in your code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim playerDict As New Dictionary(Of Int32, String) From {{2002, "Tim Wood"}, {2003, "Vince Singer"}, {2004, "Donal Clark"}, {2005, "Patrick Hartnett"}, {2006, "Peter Nicholson"}, {2007, "Chris Montgomery"}}

    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim strPlayer As String = txtPlayer.Text
        Dim years As IEnumerable(Of String) = From kvp In playerDict Where kvp.Value = strPlayer Select kvp.Key.ToString

        If years.Count <> 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show(strPlayer & " has won in the folowing years: " & String.Join(", ", years))
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(strPlayer & " has not won the tournament in the last " & playerDict.Keys.Count & " years")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You will get 5 times a messagebox "not won", and then 1 times a "won" with this solution. :)

Comment: @Jordumus whoops, I had two things going on in my head... Added a boolean flag to correct.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're trying to solve it the wrong way.

Let's get the logic going together:
We want to check the array and see if the name in the textbox is inside the array or not:

We get the string from the textbox:

```
Dim strPlayer As String = txtPlayer.Text
```

We start our loop: (we run from 0 to 5, which is 6 data points (0,1,2,3,4,5))

```
For i as Integer = 0 To 5
```

*An alternative is to change the "5" in `Player.length - 1`. Courtensy to Brandon B*

And check if we can find it:

```
if Player(i) = strPlayer then
```

If we do, we show the messagebox, and return:

```
    intYearWon = WinningYear(i)
    MessageBox.Show(strPlayer & " won in " & intYearWon)   
    Return
```

Close your if:

```
end if
```

Go to next loop:

```
next
```

If we reached this code, this means we didn't find the name.. So now we show the other textbox:

```
MessageBox.Show(strPlayer & " has not won the tournament in the last 6 years")
```

There we go.. All the code you need..

And now in 1 go:

```
Dim strPlayer As String = txtPlayer.Text
For i as Integer = 0 To 5
    if Player(i) = strPlayer then
        intYearWon = WinningYear(i)
        MessageBox.Show(strPlayer & " won in " & intYearWon)   
        Return
    end if
next
    MessageBox.Show(strPlayer & " has not won the tournament in the last 6 years")
```

Comment: You will receive an exception in your for loop when `i = 6`

Comment: Your for loop will also not compile with the `==`. You need to change to  `=` or use `strPlayer.equals(Player(i))` as I have.

Comment: I really should get the dust of my vb.net knowledge. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off
Public Class Form1
    Private Player() As String = {"Tim Wood", "Vince Singer", "Donal Clark", "Patrick Hartnett", "Peter Nicholson", "Chris Montgomery"}
    Private WinningYear() As Integer = {2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007}
    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        'Searches array for player
        Dim strPlayer As String = txtPlayer.Text
        Dim found As Boolean = False
        For i As Integer = 0 To Player.Length - 1
            If strPlayer.ToLower = Player(i).ToLower Then
                found = True
                MessageBox.Show(strPlayer & " won in " & WinningYear(i))
            End If
        Next
        If Not found Then MessageBox.Show(strPlayer & " has not won the tournament in the last 6 years")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Agreed with @TheBlueDog. However this code will also drop the string to lowercase before comparing and that may not be what the OP wants.